# Using Sum in If in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sum

I want to select the sum of values of my_field. The unit of my_field is in seconds. I don't want to exceed 24 hours, so when it exceeds 24 hours, I want it to select 24*60*60 = 86400.

```
SELECT IF(SUM(my_field) > 86400, 86400, SUM(my_field))
...
```

This solution doesn't seem to work. What else can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`least`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least) would be much easier:

```
SELECT LEAST(SUM(my_field), 86400)
FROM   my_table
```

Comment: Not SMALLEST... (or is it LEAST?)

Comment: Thanks for the answers, this gave me the idea.

Comment: @jarlh yup, that was a momentarily lapse in concentration. Indeed - `least`

Comment: @StuartLC yup - wasn't concentrating. See latest edit.

Comment: @tolga note that as noted in the above comment, it should have been `least`, not `greatest` (edited to update the answer).

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is to use `CASE` expression like

```
SELECT CASE WHEN SUM(my_field) > 86400 THEN 86400 ELSE SUM(my_field) END
FROM table1
```

Comment: Thank you, this answer is useful too.